# Is it possible in java to insert arithmetic operator(+ - / * ) in an array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I'm working on a calculator app..so i'm thinking is there any way out to store arithmetic operator in an array

Comment: Yes, of course you may store it in an array of strings.  But, as a note of caution, if you're building a calculator, the data structure onto which you probably want to be putting your operators is a _stack_, not an array.  Post some code and maybe we can say more than this.

Comment: First of all this is too broad, and secondly calculator not work that way , yes you can store operators in array of char . Search for terms like polish string and there uses which will help you.

Comment: You should spent serious time at the [help] to learn how and what to ask here. If you continue to post such low quality questions, you will be banned from asking questions at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can store them in a `char[]` or `String[]`:

```
char[] chars = new char[10];
chars[0] = '+';

String[] array = new String[10];
array[0] = "+";
```

A better way is use some kind of `Collection`, for example, `java.util.List`:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("+");
list.add("-");
list.add("*");
list.add("/");
```

Comment: On top of this, something like the [interpreter pattern](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/bytecode.html#the-interpreter-pattern) can be a useful way to store values and operators.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you **cannot store operators** in array or in variable.

Instead what you can do is store **symbols** of arithmetic operators in String or Character arrays.

Which then you can interpret as operators while coding

```
if(ch == '+')
     result = x + y;
```

This is only useful if the calculator, your making, is implementing an input field where the user can write text.